How to remove a generated attribute in ASP.NET Core TagHelper?
The following input tag helper:
<input asp-for="Query.Skip" type="hidden" name="Skip" />

renders as:
<input type="hidden" name="Skip" id="Query.Skip" value="0" />

How do I make it not render the id attribute? I don't want the id attribute. I've tried id="@null", but it still renders.

The input tag helper internally uses the registered IHtmlGenerator service, then copies the attributes. You could replace this service if you don't want any id properties. But that would probably impact labels and validation... So the bigger question is "why?"

Hm, just don't use tag helper and enter this manually, leaving id out

JeremyLakeman, yeah that might be a bit much. MichalTurczyn, that's what I was thinking after I posted the question but left it to see if there's a built-in way to ignoring the attribute I didn't know. I guess that answers that, thank you both!

You can write a simple override Tag Helper that removes the id attribute. The override Tag Helper can target specific elements versus a general service.

@DaveB, my experience with writing Tag Helpers is limited. I've only messed around when needed, and arguably to do something simple. Do you have an example I could look at to do an override Tag Helper like you suggest?

I've posted a solution. The override Tag Helper is triggered by adding a custom attribute to your input element. The custom attribute is matched to the target set by [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "noId")].

Here's a simple override Tag Helper that removes the id attribute.
Add a custom attribute that triggers the override Tag Helper. In the sample below, the attribute noId triggers the override.
In the override Tag Helper, let Razor process the default output using base.Process(context, output);.
Remove the id and custom noId attributes from the output. The end result will be:
<input type="hidden" name="Skip" value="0" />

Razor view
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel
@using WebApplication1.Helpers
@addTagHelper WebApplication1.Helpers.NoIdTagHelperTagHelper, WebApplication1
@{
}
<input noId asp-for="Query.Skip" type="hidden" name="Skip" />

NoIdTagHelper.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace WebApplication1.Helpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "noId")]
    public class NoIdTagHelperTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            base.Process(context, output);
            output.Attributes.Remove(output.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "noId"));
            output.Attributes.Remove(output.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "id"));
        }
    }
}


Exactly what I needed! Thank you! Manually writing input elements did help, but it's not as easily applied to select elements. This tag helper does exactly what I want, while allowing me to use the input and select tag helpers and their data binding abilities. Makes the whole experience much more natural. Thanks again!

I'm glad that worked. In case you need to make very specific changes to the output of an input element or select element, add the tag name to the HtmlTargetElement target. E.g. [HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = "noId")].
